# Use Current Location to draw poly lines to a destination on Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, gps, currentlocation

I have an application with a google map, the application gets my current location, there are two markers on the map, one point of the marker and the polyline are coordinates passed from a previous screen. I want the starting point of the poly line to be my current location. I also want to use my current location for the first marker. If the polyline and marker will change position as the driver moves, that will be great. But this is not a priority now.

What I have done so far: I am able to get my current location. I am able to draw polyline from a hardcoded coordinates from a source location to a destination location(the destination location was provided using hardcode Cordinate)

What I want to do: Use my current location as the starting point of my polyline Use my current location, Update the polyline and the marker when the User moves.

Here is the code I have so far.

```html
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_mao/constants.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class OrderTrackingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderTrackingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderTrackingPage> createState() => OrderTrackingPageState();
}

class OrderTrackingPageState extends State<OrderTrackingPage> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  static const snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text(
        "Problem Ahead Please Change Route, if you cannot change route then please proceed with carefull"),
  );
  static const LatLng sourceLocation =
      LatLng(-5.163422787901919, 119.4524314848277);
  static const LatLng problem1 = LatLng(-5.159517091944005, 119.44694331116966);
  static const LatLng problem2 = LatLng(-5.167239534487095, 119.40174159126605);
  static const LatLng destination =
      LatLng(-5.1670891353015715, 119.42620389739191);
  double distanceSourceFinish = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
      sourceLocation.latitude,
      sourceLocation.longitude,
      destination.latitude,
      destination.longitude);

  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  LocationData? currentLocation;
  late LocationData newLoc;

  getCurrentLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();

    location.getLocation().then(
      (location) {
        currentLocation = location;
      },
    );

    location.onLocationChanged.listen((newLoc) {
      currentLocation = newLoc;

      double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(newLoc.latitude!,
          newLoc.longitude!, problem1.latitude, problem1.longitude);
      print(newLoc);
      print("distance : " + distanceInMeters.toInt().toString() + " m");
      print("longitude : " + newLoc.longitude.toString());
      print("latitude : " + newLoc.latitude.toString());
      if (distanceInMeters.toInt() <= 200) {
        print(
            "Problem Ahead Please Change Route, if you cannot change route then please proceed with carefull");
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  addPolyLine(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 8,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

  getPolyline() async {
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      google_api_key,
      PointLatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!),
      PointLatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
    );
    print("result" + result.toString());
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    } else {
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }
    
    addPolyLine(polylineCoordinates);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentLocation();
    getPolyline();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 31, 14),
        title: const Text(
          "Route Maps",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
      body: currentLocation == null
          ? Center(
              child: Text(
              "Loading",
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              ),
            ))
          : Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.satellite,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!,
                          currentLocation!.longitude!),
                      zoom: 16),
                  polylines: {
                    Polyline(
                        polylineId: PolylineId("route"),
                        points: polylineCoordinates,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 222, 35),
                        width: 6)
                  },
                  markers: {
                    Marker(
                        markerId: const MarkerId("currentLocation"),
                        position: LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!,
                            currentLocation!.longitude!),
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow)),
                    Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId("source"),
                        position: sourceLocation,
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueAzure)),
                    Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId("Problem"),
                        position: problem1,
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueRed)),
                    Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId("destination"),
                        position: destination,
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueCyan)),
                  },
                  onMapCreated: (mapController) {
                    _controller.complete(mapController);
                  },
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 20.0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 6.0,
                      horizontal: 12.0,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      boxShadow: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          blurRadius: 6.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Distance : " +
                          //distanceCurrentProblem.toInt().toString() +
                          distanceSourceFinish.toInt().toString() +
                          " m",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This [article/tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/implement-real-time-location-updates-on-google-maps-in-flutter-235c8a09173e) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use geoLocator Pkg, which solves my problem as I move the marker and polyline updated.

```
Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
    .listen((event) async {
  
   source.value = event;
  await getPointes();

  
});
```

event is the current updated location as I move forward and backward